# How to tell if an iterable can be iterated only once?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

Iterables like generators can only be iterated once:

```
def f():
  for i in range(10):
    yield i
a = f()
for x in a:
  print(x) # prints x
for x in a:
  print(x) # prints none
```

Iterables like `list` can be iterated many times:

```
a = list(range(10))
for x in a:
  print(x) # prints x
for x in a:
  print(x) # prints x
```

How can I tell if an iterable can only be iterated once or not?

The motivation for this question comes from the implementation of [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

If we can tell if an iterable can be iterated only once, we can make the implementation more memory-efficient:

```
def cycle(iterable):
    it = iterable
    if only_iterated_once(iterable):
       it = list(iterable)
    while True:
        for element in it:
              yield element
```

If the argument can be iterated multiple times, we don't need to save an additional copy.

Comment: There is no way to tell if all you know is that it is an iterable, however, all **iterators** should be only a single pass. So, `iter(iterable) is iterable` is a very good indicator that it is single pass

Comment: Do you have any documentation about this? It looks strange to me there is no way to tell it.

Comment: How could you possibly tell? You can implement an iterable any way you *want*. You can read about the iterator protocol in Python to search for docs. But generally, **all correctly implemented iterators** are single pass (this is not enforced by the language though). All built in containers can be iterated multiple times.

Comment: Yes, ``iterators`` are just for a simple pass. I'm talking about ``iterable``, however.

Comment: how about `print(type(a))` ?

Comment: Well, *all built in iterables that aren't iterators* are multiple pass, and all built in iterators are single pass (with the exception of file base iterators that can be "reset" by using `.seek`... ). Note generators are iterators

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then I find inconsistency: 1. generators are iterators. 2. ``itertools.cycle`` requires an iterable as an argument, but passing an iterator to it also works.

Comment: @youkaichao: Iterators are, themselves, iterable. e.g. `it = iter([]); iter(it) is it`. (Also, the “more memory-efficient” implementation isn’t correct… and isn’t more memory-efficient either. It doesn’t yield values as soon as it gets them and doesn’t work for infinite iterables.)

Comment: There is no inconsistency, iterators **are iterables**

Comment: So if an object is an iterator and an iterable, it can be iterated only once. If an object is an ``iterable`` but not an iterator, it can be iterated multiple times?

Comment: 1. yes; 2. no. It’s valid to make an iterable that can’t be iterated over multiple times.

Comment: Yes, but of course, any user-defined iterable could be implemented to only be single pass (but that would be strange)

Comment: Seems like all [`Collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) can be *iterated* more than once so checking if something is an instance of  `collections.abc.Collection`  would work/help. Or checking if the thing as the `__len__` attribute as well as `__iter__` and/or `__next__`.

Comment: Looks like that would be safe for all *built-in* objects but you probably can't rely on that for user-defined bjects.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between your examples is that in the generator example, a single iterator is created before the loops happen, then that same iterator is used twice. In the list example however, a new iterator is used for each loop.

---

In the first example, a generator is an iterator itself. When you do

```
a = f()
```

The call to `f` creates a generator (which is an iterator). When you give `a` to the `for` loops, they call `iter` on `a`, which **returns itself**. A short MCVE shows this easily:

```
l = [1]
i = iter(l)

j = iter(i)

print(i is j)  # Prints True
```

One iterator is used for both loops. This means that by the time the second loop starts, the shared iterator will already be exhausted.

---

In the second example however, when `for` calls `iter` on `a`, a new iterator is created, *each time*; so *two iterators are created*. This means that each loop uses its own iterator, so the second loop isn't using an exhausted iterator.

---

---

In other words, the way to tell is to think about whether or not you're creating a new iterator with each use, or using an old iterator multiple times.

Comment: But python developers say it is impossible: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/17783

Comment: @youkaichao When I posted this answer, you hadn't posted the `cycle` part, so I interpreted the question as you asking why there was a difference in behaviour. No, there likely is no reliable programmatic way of telling.